# how to add s3 files to docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-s3

I am a newbie to docker. I am trying to deploy a R app as a docker image. I am able to deploy the app in docker by mounting the folder. But I don't think that is going to work in AWS. I am thinking of storing my app in s3 and adding it during the build by ADD command. But it is throwing me this error :
**ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder441270805/s3:/bucket_name/app: no such file or directory**

Can you guys please give me any idea on how to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder441270805/s3:/bucket_name/app` is not a valid path, docker simply can't find anything there.

Possible solutions:

1. [mount the s3 folder](https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/) to a local folder and use that instead.
2. Make the bucket publically available and download the app in the
   Dockerfile using curl/wget or whatever.

Option 1 has the advantage of having to change very little to your current workflow while option 2 would allow anyone with access to the bucket to be able to build the dockerfile without having to do anything to the underlying os / file structure.

**Note** downloading the files from s3 might not always work, the docker cache is rather aggressive and may cause issues when you want the updated output to make it into a new container.

For more info see [this](https://thenewstack.io/understanding-the-docker-cache-for-faster-builds/) blog post.

Comment: Just be aware that the curl command might hit docker build cash and no download happens even if the file changed in the s3

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of that, lemme add it to the answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for the prompt reply. I really appreciate that. I am trying to deploy the container in ec2. In that case how will step 1 help ? Can I mount the s3 bucket or its folders in the container ? Thanks

Comment: It does not matter where you host it as the files will be added from your machine when you do the build. The files will actually end up in the layer you build.

Comment: HI. Thanks for the help. I am able to deploy docker container by following the advice. Thank you very much.